# How well can proteins discriminate between ATP and GTP? Can ATP act as a GTP mimetic?

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, literature, protein-binding, phosphorylation

GTP and ATP are similar structures with the adenosine and guanosine groups differing. Both are involved in a vast array of biological functions.

However it has been shown that in certain cases, GTP and water *can* mimic ATP ([Niefind *et al.,* 1999](http://www.nature.com/nsmb/journal/v6/n12/full/nsb1299_1100.html)).

[image: An image of GTP and ATP side by side. GTP has an additional NH2 group. ATP has an NH2 group where GTP has a double bonded oxygen.]

Are there examples where ATP has acted as a mimetic of GTP? Or in other words, are there any proteins that can't discriminate between GTP and ATP very well?

Comment: There are certainly some enzymes that don't discriminate (well) between the two purines. Is that what you mean by mimic?